# C# Mail.Attachment size issue

Tags: c#, email, filestream, email-attachments, memorystream

My Requirement is to create an in-memorystream, write lines of string to the stream and then email the content in the memory stream using Mail.Attachment type in c#,

Find the code below,

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter memoryWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);

----- *WRITE 100+ LINES OF STRINGS* using memory.Writer object
```

now I am creating an Mail.Attachment object as

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(memoryStream,        GetFileName());
```

ISSUE: The attachment does not contain all the content thats in MemoryStream,
Is there a max-size property on the Attachment object, anyway to increase the size to max so that I could write all the content from memorystream to the attachment and mail it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your 100+ lines of strings, but prior to creating the attachment, try calling:

```
memoryWriter.Flush();
```

You may have some text still in the StreamWriter's buffer that's not making it into the MemoryStream.

Comment: that worked....missed the Flush()....flush will clear the buffer and write any unwritten bytes to the stream

Comment: Additionally, in my experience, it is also good to add memoryStream .Position = 0;